# Как я могу использовать шорткод в быстром просмотре продукта woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Мне нужно разместить слайдер сопутствующих товаров в окне быстрого просмотра продукта. Я выяснил, что изначально в виджетах нельзя выводить шорткоды, но есть трюк с добавление кода

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

в конец function.php что бы отражать шорткоды в виджетах сайдбара. Я уверен на 100% что подобное есть для быстрого просмотра или мини корзины или других виджетов, но я не смог найти такого, знаете ли вы решение моей задачи?
Спасибо.

Comment: В новых (блочных) виджетах шорткоды можно использовать.

Comment: Быстрый просмотр и мини-корзина вроде как не относиться к блочным

Comment: Ни быстрых просмотров ни мини-корзин нет в WC. Это вопросы темы.